# How can I separate columns while reading an excel documents if the original format from excel combines all columns in only one separated by ","?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel document that has the information of 3 columns in only one separated by ",". I want to separate the columns during the pd.read_excel(). I tried to use usecols but it did not work. I would like also to name the columnus while calling pd.read_excel().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQU18.png)

Comment: Why is this tagged `e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text inside your excel is comma sep. One way to do is simply convert that excel to text before reading like so.

your excel

```
   a,b,c
0  1,2,3
1  4,5,6
```

Convert to text & read again.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    pd.read_excel('file.xlsx').to_string(file, index=False)


df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep = ",")
print(df)
```

Which prints #

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

> Pandas provide a method to split string around a passed separator/delimiter. After that, the string can be stored as a list in a series or it can also be used to create multiple column data frames from a single separated string. It works similarly to Python’s default split() method but it can only be applied to an individual string. Pandas str.split() method can be applied to a whole series. .str has to be prefixed every time before calling this method to differentiate it from Python’s default function otherwise, it will throw an error. [Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-split-strings-into-two-list-columns-using-str-split/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your `.xlsx` file is formatted but it looks you should be using `pandas.read_csv()` instead. Link [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

So maybe something llike `pandas.read_csv(filename, sep=',', names=['Name', 'Number', 'Gender'])`